# How to count and Group data based on consecutive occurrence in pyspark using structured streaming

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am receiving continuous stream of temperature data from Kafka. I am classifying the data based on temperature ranges as below.

```
Timestamp         alertType
5/1/2019 10:01:10   MEDIUM
5/1/2019 10:01:11   MEDIUM
5/1/2019 10:01:12   MEDIUM
5/1/2019 10:01:13   MEDIUM
5/1/2019 10:01:14   MEDIUM
5/1/2019 10:01:15   NORMAL
5/1/2019 10:01:16   HIGH
5/1/2019 10:01:17   HIGH
5/1/2019 10:01:18   HIGH
5/1/2019 10:01:19   MEDIUM
```

How do I get the output using pyspark using window function with some sliding interval (1 sec). If the number of consecutive count is above threshold then i want to trigger an alert.

```
Timestamp         alertType Count
5/1/2019 10:01:14   MEDIUM  5
5/1/2019 10:01:15   NORMAL  1
5/1/2019 10:01:18   HIGH    3
5/1/2019 10:01:19   MEDIUM  1
```

Is there an alternate way to achieve the'lag' functionality with structured streaming?